# $f(c)\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) \phi(x) dx =g(c)\int_{1}^{\infty} g(x) \phi(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, general-topology, improper-integrals

> If $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[1,\infty)$ and $\phi(x)\geq0$ and be integrable in $[1,\infty) $. Also $ \int_{1}^{\infty}\phi(x) dx \neq 0$ and $ \int_{1}^{\infty} g(x) \phi(x) dx \neq 0$ then there exists some
> $c\in(1,\infty)$ such that
> $$
> g(c)\int_1^\infty f(x) \phi(x) dx =
>      f(c)\int_1^\infty g(x) \phi(x) dx
> $$

**MY TRY** - Let
$$
\frac{\int_1^\infty f(x) \phi(x) dx}
     {\int_1^\infty g(x) \phi(x) dx} = \lambda
$$
so
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}  (f(x)-\lambda g(x)) \phi(x)dx =0
$$
After this i am stuck.

Comment: You only want one pair of dollar signs around an entire expression. I've fixed that for you.

Comment: @J.G. thanks. Any hints for the problem??

Comment: @gt6989b Thanks

Comment: In your attempt, don't forget the parentheses: the last line should be $\int^\infty_1 \big( f(x) - \lambda g(x)\big) \phi(x) dx = 0$.

Comment: @ccroth Thanks. Any ideas to attack the problem?

Comment: @ Oliver Diaz generalised mean value theorem is for definite integrals.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz see the mean value theorem is for definite integrals. http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integ/integ04/integ04.html

Comment: @Oliver Diaz that c will depend on some variable n

Comment: @Oliver Diaz Please give some more ideas. I like your idea

Comment: @Oliver Diaz can you please provide your idea. Please

Answer (score 3):

If
$$\int_1^\infty (f(x) - \lambda g(x))\phi(x)dx =0$$
With $\phi \geq 0$ (and $\phi \not\equiv 0$), then by continuity, there must be some $c\in(1,\infty)$ such that $f(c) - \lambda g(c) = 0$, otherwise if $f(x) -\lambda g(x) >0$ for all $x\in(1,\infty)$, the integral would be positive. If $f(x) - \lambda g(x) < 0$ for all $x\in(1,\infty)$ the integral would be negative.

**Edit:**
I will discuss the case when $g(c) =0$ as this implies $f(c)=0$ and $\lambda =1$. I have shown
$$\exists c\in (1,\infty), \text{ such that } g(c)\int_1^\infty f(x)\phi(x)dx = f(c)\int_1^\infty g(x)\phi(x)dx, \quad (1)$$

As a counter example to the original claim
$$\exists c\in (1,\infty), \text{ such that } \frac{\int_1^\infty f(x)\phi(x)dx}{\int_1^\infty g(x) \phi(x)dx} = \frac{f(c)}{g(c)}, \quad (2)$$

Consider taking $\phi = 1_{[1,4]}$, and $f$ to be a bump function with support in $[1,2]$ and $g$ a shifted bump function of $f$ with support in $[3,4]$. This implies $\lambda =1$ and
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty(f(x) - \lambda g(x))\phi(x)dx &= \int_1^4(f(x) - g(x))dx 
\\
&= \int_1^2 f(x)dx - \int_3^4g(x)dx =0
\end{align}
But there is no point $c\in [1,\infty)$ such that
$$\frac{f(c)}{g(c)} = 1$$
since $f \equiv 0$ on the support of $g$. Therefor you cannot guarantee (2), but you Can guarentee the exitence of $c\in (1,\infty)$ for the equality (1). In this example $f(2.5) = g(2.5) = 0$.

Comment: Integral also contains $\phi$. How is the integral positive if f(x)-$\lambda$g(x)>0??

Comment: @user775902 Because $\phi \geq 0$

Comment: so integral can be equal to 0?

Comment: I want c in open interval (1,$\infty$). How does this solution provide me that?

Comment: @ I got a c $\in$[1,$\infty$). How to exclude c=1.?

Comment: @user775902 You can take $c\in (1,\infty)$ (I changed it now) since $\{1\}$ has zero measure, so my proof by contradiction will follow either way. Continuity is what's important here.

Comment: How to exclude c=1? Please answer.

Comment: Can you please provide a short proof that c$\neq$ 1

Comment: Please provide that proof by contadiction. c$\neq $1 is really important

Comment: @user775902 Read my comment, it is sufficient.

Comment: I cannot get it. Please include it in the answer itself. Please

Comment: Please provide a proof. Please.

Comment: @Dayton How do you conclude that g(c)$\neq$0. To divide by g(c) it must be non zero.

Comment: @user775902 See the updated case when $g(c) = 0$. Your original question was actually false if you look at my counter example.